# PHP/MongoDB - Add subdocument to document with _id

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to learn MongoDB with PHP.  I can successfully save a new document with ->save($object).  My goal is to add a subdocument to a document with a specific _id.

I have a document:

```
"5197f4bef045a1d710000032": {
"_id": {
  "$id": "5197f4bef045a1d710000032"
},
"tag": 5487,
"serial": "1z5589ss56",
"type": "Soda Can",
"dept": "NOC",
"location": "Mitchell",
"date": 1368913086,
"moves": null
}
```

I would like to insert a new document into "moves".

I have been able to once with $set, however subsequent $push does nothing.

```
    <?php


$m = new Mongo();

$d = $m->selectDB('peeps');
$c = $d->family;
$fields = array('tag' => 5487 , 'serial' => '1z5589ss56', 'type' => 'Soda Can', 'dept' => 'NOC', 'location' => 'Mitchell', 'date' => time() );

$can = new Asset($fields);
#$c->save($can);

#Update to insert move

$c->update(array('_id' => new MongoID('5197f0cef045a1d710000032')), array('$push' => array('moves' => $can)));


$cur = $c->find();
$J = json_encode(iterator_to_array($cur));
print($J);


class Asset{

    public $tag;
    public $serial;
    public $type;
    public $dept;
    public $location;
    public $date;
    public $moves;

    public function __construct($fields){
        $this->tag = $fields['tag'];
        $this->serial = $fields['serial'];
        $this->type = $fields['type'];
        $this->dept = $fields['dept'];
        $this->location = $fields['location'];
        $this->date = $fields['date'];
    }
}
```

Based on what I have read, this should create a nested document inside 5197f0cef045a1d710000032.moves every time I reload the page.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Thanks,

Mitchell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using $set with a simple value if you plan on later using `$push` to the same field.

Use `$push` the first time you update also.   It will create an array of a single element, and then you will be able to add (push) more elements to it.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am not sure why I was unable to find the tree in the forest. :)